# Creating a pure python API (without any framework) where postman client can successfully post json requests

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests

Below is what I have tried.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import requests

PORT = 8000

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()

def api(data):
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api', json=data)
    return r.json()
```

Getting below error with above code.

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Postman should be able to send post request having json body.

Comment: what do you try to do with this code? Your function `api`  is totally useless. You have to read documentation to see how to create HTTP server. You created server which have not function to get and send data - and maybe this is why it refuse connection.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you check [SimpleHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) then you see `do_GET`, `do_HEAD` but it doesn't have `do_POST` so it can't get `POST` request - you have to create own class with `do_POST`. But this function may need a lot code to get data and send data back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show full error message and I don't use Windows to test it but `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` doesn't have function `do_POST` to receive `POST` request and this can make problem.

You will have to use `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` to create own class with `do_POST`.

And this function will need to

- get header information
- read JSON string
- convert request data from JSON string to dictionary
- convert response data from dictionary to JSON string
- send headers
- send JSON string

so it will need a lot of work.

Minimal working server

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import json

PORT = 8000

class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def do_POST(self):
        # - request -
        
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        #print('content_length:', content_length)
        
        if content_length:
            input_json = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            input_data = json.loads(input_json)
        else:
            input_data = None
            
        print(input_data)
        
        # - response -
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
        self.end_headers()
        
        output_data = {'status': 'OK', 'result': 'HELLO WORLD!'}
        output_json = json.dumps(output_data)
        
        self.wfile.write(output_json.encode('utf-8'))


Handler = MyHandler

try:
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print(f"Starting http://0.0.0.0:{PORT}")
        httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping by Ctrl+C")
    httpd.server_close()  # to resolve problem `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`
```

And testing code

```
import requests

data = {'search': 'hello world?'}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api', json=data)
print('status:', r.status_code)
print('json:', r.json())
```

This example doesn't check if you run `/api` or `/api/function` or `/api/function/arguments` because it would need much more code.

So pure python API without framework can need a lot of work and it can be waste of time.

---

The same code with `Flask`. It is much shorter and it already checks if you send to `/api`.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def api():
    input_data = request.json
    print(input_data)
    output_data = {'status': 'OK', 'result': 'HELLO WORLD!'}
    return jsonify(output_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you want to test post data then you can use portal http://httpbin.org and send `POST` request to http://httpbin.org/post and it will send back all data and headers.

It can be used also for other requests and data.

This portal was created with Flask and there is even link to source code so you can install it on own computer.

---

It seems `httpbin` is part of `Postman` repo on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed solution and information. Many thanks!

Comment: `httpd` is not accessible to the `except` statement cause it's scoped by `with`, I think this would work

`with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    try:
        print(f"Starting http://0.0.0.0:{PORT}")
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping by Ctrl+C")
        httpd.server_close()`