# Python HTTP Requests - Receive data from Webhook

Tags: python, http, request, odoo

I know its probably pretty simple to solve this issue but I just dont seem to find any good solution to it...

I basically have an API Endpoint which is supposed to accept data that is coming in from a Webhook sending that data. The problem is that I dont know how to get this data / to use this data. In addition I cant use frameworks like flask.

Example:
The Webhook sends me json data: "test": "test_value"
How would I now be able to use this pair?

I tried to use the requests library but seems like nothing is working with it.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`requests` library is completely unrelated to receiving data from webhooks. It's for sending requests, which is basically the opposite of what you want to do as you're the one sending data and receiving a response.

You need an API endpoint like you said. If you in fact have one, you can skip this paragraph. If not, there are many ways to create one. Frameworks like `flask` or `django` are the most common one. If you can't use them for some random reason, you can implement functionality like this yourself. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67962816/7264739) one of many examples.

Also note that the endpoint has to be accessible by external requests. For instance, if your server/code is whitelisting IPs, you need to add IPs to the list. They're not always documented though.

Then you can set the webhook up to connect to your endpoint. You usually do that in control panels of services that provide the webhook.